# spring security with custom login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to use a custom login page. By default the login-processing-url is /j_spring_security_check but in my case I don't want to set the /j_spring_security_check in the action attribute of my login form, instead I am using a custom action(method in the login controller). The problem is that using my code I can't use the in-memory list of users (jimi, bob) no authentication is achieved so my application keeps redirecting me to the login page. Do I have to create my own filter in place of the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter? Any ideas? Hope I've made myself clear.

```
  <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/mysite/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/mysite/login" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/mysite/home" always-use-default-target="false""/>
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
  </security:http>  

  <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
      <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="jimi" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:user name="bob" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
  </security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete security configuration in your question?

Comment: You want a different html login page or a different Authentication method?

Comment: If you don't want to use `/j_spring_security_check` url then you need to specify different url in `login-processing-url` attribute.

Comment: Finally I used a custom UserDetailsService and UserDetails(classes which implement these interfaces) and I have changed the in memory users with users in the database.In my spring security xml configuration I have this set this authentication manager <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager><bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"><property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService"/></bean>